# Truncating text within a span within a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, truncate, ellipsis

I have a table setup to truncate text perfectly.... until I wrap the text in that table into a div. See this JSFiddle as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/3DKMJ/

This works for truncating the text in the cell:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This does not work for truncating the text in the cell:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div>Text</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my css:

```
table {border:1px solid #000; width:100px;table-layout: fixed;}
td { width:100px;white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

The thing about the div is that it still prevents the text from wrapping, and the text is just hidden, but the ellipses that I have set to show don't show with the div attached.

Any ideas how to get this to work when there are div's within the table?

[EDIT] As mentioned, I could add `td, td div {` to it and that will work. I realized this after posting, my problem seems to be more specific. I actually have a span that is being displayed as an inline block. I assumed it was the block part that was causing problems, but I guess it is the fact that it is a span with an inline block. See this upadted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2PZW/2/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `display:inline;` on the `div` elements in question.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3DKMJ/1/)

---

**In reply to question edit:**

Use `display:inline` instead of `display:inline-block` on your `td span`.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2PZW/3/)

---

**In reply to comments:**

If you really need to keep it as `display:inline-block`, you can do it like this:

```
td span {
   display:inline-block; 
   text-overflow:ellipsis;
   overflow:hidden; 
   width:100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P2PZW/5/)

Comment: But for this scenerio I need to use an inline-block. inline doesn't do the same thing. Maybe this just isn't possible?

Comment: @BlueCaret Why do you have to use inline-block?

Comment: Well truth be told I was able to work around this so i don't need an inline-block but I'm just trying to future proof this so if anyone were to add an inline block to it that it would still work.

Comment: @BlueCaret Check out my edit, I've also got a way to keep it inline-block.

Comment: I see. So because it's an inline-block it needs the width on it as well. Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
td, td div { width:100px;white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

instead

```
td { width:100px;white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```